# How to retrieve stdobject property outside the foreach

Tags: php

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [rating] => 2
            )

    )
```

I'm trying to get like this

```
foreach ($star_1 as $key) 
        {
            print_r($key->rating);
        }
```

How do I get the `rating` value outside the foreach

Answer (score 2):

This value is an array containing elements of type `stdClass`. These elements have fields that can be accessed using `element->field_name`. Since you want to access the **rating** of the **first** element in your array (= at index 0), you should use

```
$array[0]->rating
```

Comment: How should I retrieve it outside the foreach.Can you please explain it as using foreach

Comment: If  `$array` contains the value you described in your original post, `$array[0]->rating` will contain "2". Isn't this your question?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you said.. :( Anyway My array value is like this as defined in my post.just giving `$array[0]->rating` retrieve it..!!

Comment: My array name is something like this `$star_1`

Comment: Well... just use $star_1[0]->rating then